# Strange behaviour with openssl subject-alternative-name extension

Tags: attributes, openssl

I'm trying to use openssl to generate a certification with multiple alternative name.

I have my CA and its certification and its key.

Now, I have generate a ceritificate request with some subject-alternative-name and with command  `openssl req -text -noout -in domain.csr`  I've seen that is right with the extension subject-alternative-name in attributes.

In `openssl.cnf` I have set `copy_extensions = copy`.

The problem is that when I generate the certification I get the certification but there isn't  extension subject-alternative-name in attributes.

What kind of problem it can be?

Answer (score 0):

I the openssl config, you need to have the SAN section, and you need to keep it until you issue it for yourself.

On my page you can find my generator tool for SSLs requests. Maybe this will help you.

http://vargaviktor.hu/openssl_generator_en.html